# How to retain a selected value in dynamically generated dropdown box to the next jsp page?

Tags: javascript, jsp, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down box where the options are coming from the configured properties file.The options are generated on load of the page.I have used the following code.

In JSP

```
<select name="IDNo" id="IDNo">                  
</select>

function loading()
{           
        var d = document.getElementById("system");
        var df=document.getElementById("IDNo");

        var i = 0;
        var disp = document.getElementById("Range");

        var numberOfOptions = df.options.length;
        for (i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {                  
            df.remove(0);
        }  
        if (d.value == "Apple") {
            df.options[df.options.length] = new Option("ALL","");           
            for(i=1;i<=disp.value;i++)
            {  
                var option = document.createElement("option");                  
                option.text=i;
                option.value=i;
                df.add(option, df.options[null]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi..i want to retain the text of selected option in dropdown box in the next page.help me fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like the following at the end of the code:

```
<c:if test="${!empty param.IDNo}">
    for (var i = 0; i < df.options.length; i++) {
        if (df.options[i].value == '${param.IDNo}') {
            df.selectedIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the simple java script function to set selected value of combo or drop down box in the other page

function setSelected()

```
     {
        var Num = "<%=NumID%>";
        if(Num != null && Num !='' )
        {
           var secondCombo = document.getElementById("combo_id");
           secondCombo.value = Num;             
        }           
     }
```

Comment: Call the above function onload body of the jap page